# Using REGXP_LIKE within queryExecute()

Tags: sql, oracle, coldfusion

I'm looking to modify an existing query to use REGEXP_LIKE but falling foul of some syntax I'm not understanding properly. We've currently a CF query into an Oracle DB using the following:

```
result = QueryExecute("
  SELECT paramOne, paramTwo FROM someTable WHERE fieldOne = :PUBLISHER
", {PUBLISHER=publisherId}, {datasource="someDB"});
```

which works. However, I want to modify the underlying query to be:

```
result = QueryExecute("
  SELECT paramOne, paramTwo FROM someTable WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(fieldOne, '(^|,)(:PUBLISHER)($|,)', 'i')
", {PUBLISHER=publisherId}, {datasource="someDB"});
```

but it's not delivering the expected results. A few things I've noted as I try to debug...

- The underlying query(without using a variable) works and has been verified in Oracle SQL
- If I go to the source code and replace :PUBLISHER with a 'hard coded' value the things work as expected.
- I've tried escaping the ':' but that's not the answer.

I fell there's something I'm not understanding about passing variables into a REGEX expression within `queryExecute()`, so would appreciate any thoughts.

Any input gratefully received,
Phil

Comment: Hi Phil. Would you mind sharing the full use case. DDL and simple insert statement for row?

Comment: @DomG - thanks for looking at this, but the suggestion below has cracked it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SQL> 
with t (fieldOne) as  (
  select 'abc, def' from dual union all
  select 'def cba' from dual union all
  select ':publisher' from dual
)
select * from t where REGEXP_LIKE(fieldOne, '(^|,)(:PUBLISHER)($|,)', 'i');

FIELDONE  
----------
:publisher

SQL> 
with t (fieldOne) as  (
  select 'abc, def' from dual union all
  select 'def cba' from dual union all
  select ':publisher' from dual
)
select * from t where REGEXP_LIKE(fieldOne, '(^|,)(' || :PUBLISHER || ')($|,)', 'i');

FIELDONE  
----------
abc, def
```